# VS 2008 is auto changing my CSS file

Tags: css, styles

I just migrated an web app from vs 2005 to vs 2008.  I use a CSS file with styles for my buttons.  In Vs2005, if I assign a style and elect to change it, I would get an inline style for that button, thus creating an exception to my style.  In 2008 (also tried this in 2010) it will change the width setting in my CSS file if I resize a button... thus making a global change.
Is there a way to turn this off?  I have looked most everywhere and do not see this issue on the web.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use in VS 2010 Skin and Theme to apply formatting to your Button. There is also a SkinId property which allow you to set a specific Style for a Web Control with that the same Id. Have a look at MS reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx